# Can you configure IIS7 to use SSL for some pages but not others?

Tags: windows, iis-7

We are deploying a MVC2 site to production and would like to restrict SSL to the login and home pages (Home page has a login box also). Is this a job for Url Rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, URL Rewrite is great for this.

IIS itself makes SSL an option for you, but it's up to you to point users to https and back again in your HTML/site.  URL Rewrite then serves as a good layer of protection in case anyone bookmarks a page or types it in manually, or if you miss something in the HTML.

In URL Rewrite, use {HTTPS} = off and {URL} to check if the page needs to be redirected to https.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the quick reply. If I understand you correctly we need to make some code changes and also use the rewrite module. Yes?

Comment: Yes, the code changes aren't absolutely required, but if the links within the site directly point to the https or http absolute paths, it's cleaner.  URL Rewrite can get everything else, like direct links to your homepage and such.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to do this from your application code. It should be two or three lines at most to redirect to https://{url}?{querystring}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a bad idea except in very particular use cases. Presumably you're passing a session cookie back after the user has logged in. Unencrypted, this cookie is incredibly easy to sniff out on public networks and use to hijack the session, as [FireSheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) has probably made evident to most developers by now.

If you're serious about protecting your users' logins, then you need to protect the session cookie and not just their password.